# Visual Studio 2013: Where do "_Adding library" requests come from?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, libraries

When I compile some inherited code in VS2013, I get the following output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Conocontrol, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>       _Adding library: PGL7ud.lib: MFC7.0, Debug, UNICODE
1>       _Adding library: IGfx7ud.lib: MFC7.0, Debug, UNICODE
1>       _Adding library: gdiplus.lib
```

Where do the requests for these libraries come from?  I've searched the source code and Project Properties and even opened the .sln and .vcxproj files in Notepad++, and cannot find how they are being requested.  I need to remove the references to the first two because they no longer exist.

Comment: These messages are generated with `#pragma message` by whatever library you include.  Google quickly locates [their source](http://read.pudn.com/downloads115/sourcecode/windows/bitmap/482805/PGL/Pgl/PGL.h__.htm).